# Exclude records with SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I have a table with 10 records.

```
SELECT * FROM Komponens WHERE fkod = "SO"
```

It gives me a table with about 5 record. But I want the result without that 5 records.

For example:

```
fkod   kkod
SU     AA
SU     AC
SA     AB
CI     AC
CI     AA
```

**fkod** is the name of spice (SU - sugar, SA - salt, CI - cinnamon) and **kkod** is the name of the mixture of spices. I'm out of sugar and I want to show the mixtures that I *can* create, because there is no sugar needed for them (in this case just `SA` - `AB`).

If I use `SELECT * FROM Komponens WHERE fkod != "SU"` I get AB, AC and AA.

How can I solve it in SQL?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - could you please clarify. Do you mean that you want to exclude these 5 records?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question :)

Comment: when you say 'fkod = "SO",' do you mean 'fkod = "SU"'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amend to work with the new logic. Please try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Komponens
WHERE kkod NOT IN (
    SELECT kkod
    FROM Komponens
    WHERE fkod = "SU"
)
```

Comment: Uh, It's my fault, sorry. It's not my problem. 
For example:

fkod   kkod
SU   AA
SU   AC
SA   AB
CI   AC
CI   AA

fkod is the name of spice ( SU - sugar, SA - salt, CI - cinnamon )
kkod is the name of the mixture of spices.
I'm out of sugar and I want to show the mixtures that I can create, because they don't need the sugar (AB).

If I use SELECT * FROM Komponens WHERE fkod != "SU" I get AB,AC and AA. 

So this is my problem. I'm very sorry :S

Comment: @mitya I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do. Could you post a sample of the data in the table?

Comment: @mitya I've check your amened question and I think I understand what you are trying to do, I've amended my original answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM Komponens WHERE (fkod <>"SO") or (fkod is null)
```

given the added explanation, acatt's answer is correct, identify the kkod's with fkod = SU, then identify the rows with kkod's outside that set.

The only other way I can think of to write the SQL is:

```
SELECT k.* 
FROM Komponens k left outer join
(select kkod from Komponens WHERE fkod = "SU" group by kkod) l
on k.kkod   = l.kkod   
where l.kkod is null
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work in Access but

```
SELECT * FROM Komponens WHERE fkod = "SU"
SELECT * FROM Komponens WHERE fkod != "SU"
```

gives you those with sugar and those without sugar, so ...

```
SELECT * FROM Komponens WHERE fkod != "SU" 
AND kkod NOT IN (SELECT * FROM Komponens WHERE fkod = "SU")
```

I've not tested it but it should put you on the right lines.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a table that contains one record per mixture? That seems to be missing from your database.  Nonetheless, you can still solve your problem:

```
 SELECT * FROM Komponens K1 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM Komponens K2 WHERE K2.kkod = K1.kkod AND K2.fkod = 'SA')
```

or

```
 SELECT * FROM Komponens K1 WHERE kkod NOT IN 
     (SELECT kkod FROM Komponens WHERE fkod = 'SA')
```

These will give you the mixtures and all spice ingredients for the mixtures you can make without sugar.  If you only want the list of mixtures, without multiple lines for each mixture, change `SELECT *` to `SELECT DISTINCT kkod`.